# Using a range filter in a greatest-n-per-group subquery has very poor performance

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I've got a fairly simple query (being used as a subquery in a `greatest-n-per-group` situation). The `state_id` is the primary key - everything else is non-unique.

```
SELECT max(states.state_id) AS max_state_id
FROM states
WHERE states.created >= '2017-06-10 21:53:38.977455'
  AND states.created < '2017-06-26 07:00:00'
GROUP BY states.entity_id;
```

The problem is, this query is horrifically slow, and I don't believe any order of multicolumn index can solve it the way it's written. It always ends up with a `using where; using index; using temporary; using filesort`

In case it's not clear: what we're trying to do here is get the latest `state_id` for *each* `entity_id` between two timestamps.

We could instead do a `max(states.created)` (rather than `max(states.state_id)`) which is probably better anyway, but then I don't have the `state_id` for the outer query to join on.

Here's the full query including the outer part to give the full context:

```
SELECT states.state_id AS states_state_id, states.domain AS states_domain, states.entity_id AS states_entity_id, states.state AS states_state, states.attributes AS states_attributes, states.event_id AS states_event_id, states.last_changed AS states_last_changed, states.last_updated AS states_last_updated, states.created AS states_created
FROM states INNER JOIN (
    SELECT max(states.state_id) AS max_state_id
    FROM states
    WHERE states.created >= '2017-06-10 21:53:38.977455' AND states.created < '2017-06-26 07:00:00' GROUP BY states.entity_id
) AS anon_1 ON states.state_id = anon_1.max_state_id;
```

Surely there must be a way to rewrite this query in such a manner as to allow an index to do a Loose Index Scan...

Comment: Why does you outer query include all the other columns? Also, your `MAX` query could be wrong if a higher `state_id` does not mean it was created later.

Comment: @FelixPamittan: well, the outer query is simply returning the values that the application needs. We could replace that all with `select *` for brevity. As for the created vs state_id, I do agree and I mentioned that in my question. However, if we don't get the max of state_id, I am not sure how the outer query would join to it

Comment: are you querying the same time period for all ´entity_id´ ?

Comment: @Horaciux: yes, each time the query is called it's for a specific fixed time period and wants the latest state for each distinct entity

Comment: Then I'll use a temp table first, bringing max(state.created) then join to outer query

Comment: Wait a second, I just realized that I could indeed do a `max(created)` and then just join on the entity_id AND created. This would enable the same index to be used for the inner and outer queries! Let me test that...

Answer (score 0):

First, for this query:

```
SELECT max(s.state_id) AS max_state_id
FROM states s
WHERE s.created >= '2017-06-10 21:53:38.977455' AND
      s.created < '2017-06-26 07:00:00'
GROUP BY s.entity_id;
```

I would want to be sure that you have an index on `states(created, entity_d, state_id)`.  Just to see if that would help.

Second, consider rewriting the query as:

```
SELECT max(s.state_id) AS max_state_id
FROM states s
WHERE s.created >= '2017-06-10 21:53:38.977455' AND
      s.created < '2017-06-26 07:00:00' AND
      s.state_id = (SELECT MAX(s2.state_id)
                    FROM states s2
                    WHERE s2.entity_id = s.entity_id AND
                          s2.created >= '2017-06-10 21:53:38.977455' AND
                          s2.created < '2017-06-26 07:00:00'
                   );
```

For this query, you want indexes on:  `states(entity_id, created, state_id)` and `states(created, entity_id, state_id)` (the order of columns in the indexes matters).

Comment: Unfortunately, the first index doesn't work. The problem is that the second dimension is a _range_ filter that is not grouped by, with an aggregate function on a third dimension. This makes it impossible for an index to be used with the way the query is currently written. As for the query rewrite - I am testing that out...

Comment: Okay, that second query doesn't seem to work. I actually can't figure out what it's trying to do. I can say that without an index it has been running for 13 hours which feels fishy to me even if we can get it performant with an index??